# Xcode build failing no relevant error messages displayed

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am attempting to build an app from flutter on iOS but when I try to run the build I get the following error: invalid reuse after initialization failure. That is all I get in terms of an error message. I tried looking online and have not found anything relevant. I thought perhaps there was something wrong with my info.plist but I cannot find any error. Below is the info.plist contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>$(DEVELOPMENTLANGUAGE)</string>
   <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
   <string>$(EXECUTABLENAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCTBUNDLEIDENTIFIER)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>synthexklutchrelease</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(FLUTTERBUILDNAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(FLUTTERBUILDNUMBER)</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>App needs access to photo lib for profile images</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>To capture profile photo please grant camera access</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Look at menu "View > Navigators > Report Navigator", choose the 'By Time' tab,
then click the latest build. Do you see something there?

Comment: yeah this is what I got :

Comment: Showing Recent Errors Only
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: now select the line that says "Command PhaseScriptExecution", then click <All Messages>, then look above the selected line. You might see more detail.

Comment: it then simply just says build failed. Here is a screenshot,   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1orIpk9NIo1H8vOjvEzSzlLOLw0RePVlI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: that picture is from the very bottom of the list of messages. scroll up and find the line that says "Command PhaseScriptExecution". then look above that.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just ran into the same issue. I fixed it by double-clicking on Runner in the files overview. This showed Identity and Type on the right-hand side. If you set Project Format (under Project Document) to Xcode 12.0-compatible it works.

Hope the description helps. I only use the mac when testing Flutter builds for iOS, so I'm not an expert :p

Comment: If this issue still pops up later, even after selecting to `12.0-compatible`, just clean build the project, that fixed for me.

Comment: For me it helped just to restart Xcode. 
Actually, I couldn't follow your instructions, I did not find "Identity and Type on the right-hand side." 
I guess its a different issue I had.

Answer (score 82):

Cleaning the build folder (<kbd>Cmd+Shift+K</kbd>) helped me resolve the invalid reuse after initialization failure issue

Comment: Confirm. Cleaning the build helps